# javascript-single onclick event to highlight cells in different tables

Tags: javascript, html

i have a requirement to highlight cells in different tables **which are created dynamically**. i have created tables and now looking the same to highlight with some condition. my code look like as follows,

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function compare()
                 {

                var rows =document.getElementsByClassName('highlight').tBodies[0].rows, numOfRows = rows.length;


                 for (var i = 0; i < numOfRows ; i++)
                 {
                 if(rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML !== rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML )
                        {

                          rows[i].className='rowChange';
                         rows[i].cells[1].className = 'cellChange';
                          rows[i].cells[2].className = 'cellChange';
                        }}
    }
        </script>

    <body>
<div><input type="button" value="highlight" onclick="compare" /></div>
       <table id='main'>
         <tr>
            <td>table1</td>
            <td><table class='highlight' id='child1'><tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr></table></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>table2</td>
            <td><table class='highlight' id='child2'><tr><td>test2</td><td>test2</td><td>test2</td></tr></table></td>
         </tr>

           ----
           ----
          ----
         <tr>
            <td>table'n'</td>
            <td><table class='highlight' id='childn'><tr><td>test'n'</td><td>test'n'</td><td>test'n'</td></tr></table></td>
         </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

if i highlight using 'id' attribute that's working fine. but it's making code to be too complex. so please suggest me to me meet my goal efficiently. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail on what you are trying to highlight and when it would be highlighted?

Comment: Moving to use jQuery's selectors and .each() will greatly simplify your code. Worth looking into.

Comment: @ryan0319 my rqmt is to compare and highlight 1st and 2nd column data of n'number of tables which are residing inside a main table in a page.on a single button click all tables should get compared and highlighted. so far i reached this by getElementById attribute as giving id to every tables and adding same code for all tables. this is not fair as i know. so only looking the best way.

Comment: @Diodeus thanks for your suggestion, but i should do this with pure javascript only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically using the `document.getElementByClassName` incorrectly:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

The `document.getElementByClassName` does not return any `tBodies`, but the HTMLCollection of the mached elements i.e. an array of elements with the searched class.

You should also note that its IE9+ compadible, but I guess you already know that.

Anyway, the correct implementation to get the rows is this:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight')[0].rows
```

As soon as I did that change it worked like a charm.

EDIT: Well the simplest way to get your code to work is to simply add in another loop. One for the tables and one for the table rows.

```
function compare() {

    var tables =document.getElementsByClassName('highlight'), rows, numOfRows, i,j;

    for(j = 0; j < tables.length; j++) {
        rows = tables[j].rows;
        numOfRows = rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfRows ; i++)
         {
            if(rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML !== rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML )
            {
                rows[i].className='rowChange';
                rows[i].cells[1].className = 'cellChange';
                rows[i].cells[2].className = 'cellChange';
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

But this is not actually how I would advise you to do this (on the assumption you are creating the tables on the client side dynamically). The problem is that you are looking up your tables with `document.getElementByClassName` however, as you pointed out, in your actual code, you are creating the tables dynamically, with means, at the time of the creation of the tables you could simply store a reference to those tables into an array and go through that instead. There really is no need for you to use `document.getElementByClassName` you are simply taxing the system with it.

Comment: @Pihlamae i understood how to use elementsbyclassname because of u. thank u so much. but my rqmt is to compare and highlight (0,1,2)1st and 2nd column data of n'number of tables which are residing inside a main table in a page.on a single button click all tables should get compared and highlighted. so far i reached this by getElementById attribute as giving id to every tables and adding same code for all tables. this is not fair as i know. so only looking the best way. help me to get out of this. thanks in advance

Comment: @Pihlame thanks for your effort i just modified ur code above, and i got what i expected.. thank you.,. :)